# Meteor reactive variable timing

Tags: animation, meteor, css-animations, reactive-programming

So I'm in a bit over my head, even after as much research as I can I'm not sure that my question will even make that much sense.

I'm making a card game with Meteor and have a deck that is collected, shuffled, and dealt into the players hand arrays, then the database is updated. Then, in order to give animation to each card so that it looks smooth, each card is given a 'top' and 'left' property using template helpers modifying the CSS (as opposed to using templates to make things just appear and disappear).

My issue is - When I call the 'deal' function, only about half the cards go where they are supposed to. HOWEVER, if I refresh the page everything is right where it should be.

So the variables are correct, but the reactive-ness isn't quite working right? Like it seems like the reactive variable is triggering too early, before all the parameters are loaded?

Any suggestions for how to either clean up the animation system, or just trigger a manual refresh after all the dealing is done?

Again, I apologize for the uncertainty about everything.

There are 45 cards in the deck all trying to execute at once. The template is set up overall like this:

```
<template name = 'card'>
<div class = 'card' style = '
    top:{{positionTop}}px;
    left:{{positionLeft}}px'>
</div>
</template>
```

With helpers like this:

```
Template.card.helpers({
    'positionLeft':function(){
        if ('partner' === this.location){
            return this.position*50
        } else if ('hand' === this.location){
            return this.position*25
        }
    },

    'positionTop':function(){
        if ('player' === this.owner){
            return 200
        } else if ('opponent' === this.owner){
            return 400
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Does it work if you start both of your helper functions with `Template.instance();`?

Comment: To ascertain if it's really becauce of late loading of data, add a timeout inbetween and comfirm.